# Detect removal of component

Tags: java, swing

I create a `Popup` using the `PopupFactory.getPopup` method. According to the documentation, I am required to call the `hide()` method on the popup when it is no longer needed.

In my application, the popup is the child of a `JLabel` which may be removed from the current frame in a number of different situations. (Either the `JLabel` itself or one of its parent containers is removed.) Rather that calling `hide()` in every single place (and making the `Popup` object available in all these places) I would prefer to be able to detect the removal of the `JLabel` or one of its parent containers.

How can I detect the removal? I naively assumed that the removal of a component meant the removal/hiding of its children, but as the code below shows, the popup survives the removal of the `JLabel`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Xyzzy extends JFrame {
    static Xyzzy frame;
    static JPanel panel;
    static JLabel text1;
    static JLabel text2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    frame = new Xyzzy();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

                    panel = new JPanel();
                    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
                    frame.add(panel);


                    text1 = new JLabel("text1");
                    text2 = new JLabel("text2");

                    panel.add(text1);

                    frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add popup") {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
                                Popup popup = factory.getPopup(text1, new JLabel("POPUP"),frame.getX()+300,frame.getY()+300);
                                popup.show();
                            }
                        }));

                    frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("New label") {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                panel.remove(text1);
                                panel.add(text2);
                                panel.revalidate();
                            }
                        }));

                    frame.setSize(600, 600);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

This code creates a `JFrame` displaying the text "text1" and two buttons. If you press the button labeled "Add popup", a Popup with the text "POPUP" appears in the window. This Popup is a child of `text1`. Press the "New label" button and "text1" is removed from the display, but the Popup survives.

I need to be able to detect when `text1` or the containing `panel` is removed so that I can hide the popup. I want to avoid adding code where the actual `remove()` method is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HierarchyListener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
  final Popup popup = factory.getPopup(text1, new JLabel("POPUP"),frame.getX()+300,frame.getY()+300);
  text1.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {

    public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
      if (e.getID() == HierarchyEvent.HIERARCHY_CHANGED
          && (e.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED) != 0) {
        popup.hide();
      }
    }
  });
  popup.show();
}
```